# How do install TypeScript Core in ASP.NET?

Tags: angular, typescript, asp.net-core, single-page-application

I'm a bit confused, so I appreciate your patience.

I'm following [this tutorial](https://jonhilton.net/2016/12/13/angular-2-and-net-core-your-first-component/) on creating an ASP.NET Core + Angular 2 SPA. I believe I followed all the install steps, however when I go to add a new item of type "TypeScript" I see a .ts option, but in the demo its a .component.html, with a .ts file nested under. Additionally, in the Add New Item dialog box, the demo shows "TypeScript File" of type ".NET Core". While in my Add New Item dialog box, I only see "TypeScript File" of type "Client-Side".

I'm having issues with my app.module.ts recognizing my module, and I think this might be at least related.

Question: How / where do I install the .NET Core TypeScript files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have 2 files with the same name but one with a ts extension and one with a html extension, visual studio will group them together. The reason I believe is that the .html is usually the template for the class module.

You can have only ts files with a template defined in the template property of the @Component() definition

Comment: That doesn't really answer my question. Why am I not able to see the .Net Core version of a ts file?

Comment: .NET Core is a framework. TS files are TypeScript files. Both are Independent. There's no .NET Core TypeScript files.

Comment: I'm still confused. In the tutorial [screenshot](https://i2.wp.com/jonhilton.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/helloworld.png?zoom=1.25&resize=714%2C384&ssl=1) the file type says .NET Core, and the name defaults to component.ts. In my visual studio, the type says Client Side and the name defaults to ts (w/o the component).

Comment: .NET Core type project. Might be a bug in VS however, as I would have thought it would be written TypeScript File